# sql group by and null

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

They are 2 tables

```
t_employee
   ID             NUMBER,
  DEPARTMENT_ID  NUMBER,
  CHIEF_ID       NUMBER,
  NAME           VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
  SALARY         NUMBER,
  BIRTH_DATE     DATE,
  ADDRESS        VARCHAR2(200 BYTE),
  STATUS         VARCHAR2(1 BYTE)
```

and

```
t_department
  ID    NUMBER,
  NAME  VARCHAR2(100 BYTE)

BIRTH_DATE format is
day.month.year

STATUS column  is
Y or null
```

I have one question:

Print a list of employees (not managers), grouped by month of birth and status
(also replace null status to 'Not Defined').

Any idea?

Comment: you want to print a list of managers or count? If you group by you cannot obtain a list!! There is no need for the second table, What is the relation between those two tables? Post sample data and what have you tried so far

Comment: Could you please edit your question and add the code you have tried in order to get the result? We don't want to waste our efforts for someone who hasn't even tried.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
WITH T_EMPLOYEE
    AS (SELECT
             1 AS ID,
             2 AS CHIEF_ID,
             SYSDATE
             - 15000
                 AS BIRTH_DATE,
             'Y' AS STATUS
        FROM
             DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
             2 AS ID,
             3 AS CHIEF_ID,
             SYSDATE
             - 18000
                 AS BIRTH_DATE,
             'Y' AS STATUS
        FROM
             DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
             3 AS ID,
             NULL AS CHIEF_ID,
             SYSDATE
             - 19000
                 AS BIRTH_DATE,
             NULL AS STATUS
        FROM
             DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
             4 AS ID,
             3 AS CHIEF_ID,
             SYSDATE
             - 17000
                 AS BIRTH_DATE,
             NULL AS STATUS
        FROM
             DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
             5 AS ID,
             3 AS CHIEF_ID,
             SYSDATE
             - 18000
                 AS BIRTH_DATE,
             NULL AS STATUS
        FROM
             DUAL)
SELECT
      ID,
      TRUNC ( BIRTH_DATE ) AS DOB,
      NVL ( STATUS, 'Not Defined' ) AS STATUS
FROM
      T_EMPLOYEE
WHERE
      ID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT NVL ( CHIEF_ID, 0 ) FROM T_EMPLOYEE)
ORDER BY
      1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you:

```
insert into t_department values( 1, 'MANAGER');
insert into t_department values( 2, 'OTHERS');
insert into t_employee values( 1, 1, NULL ,'NAME-1', 50000, sysdate, 'ADDRESS','Y');
insert into t_employee VALUES( 2, 2, NULL, 'NAME-2', 40000, SYSDATE, 'ADDRESS','Y');

insert into t_employee values( 3, 2, null, 'NAME-3', 50000, sysdate-200, 'ADDRESS','Y');
insert into t_employee values( 4, 2, null, 'NAME-4', 40000, sysdate-100, 'ADDRESS','Y');
insert into t_employee values( 5, 2, null, 'NAME-5', 40000, sysdate-100, 'ADDRESS','Y');
insert into t_employee values( 6, 2, null, 'NAME-6', 40000, sysdate-100, 'ADDRESS',NULL);

select to_char(birth_date, 'mon') "month",
     LISTAGG(e.name||'('||NVL(e.status,'Not Defined')||')', ',') WITHIN GROUP (
ORDER BY TO_CHAR(BIRTH_DATE, 'mon')) AS lists
FROM t_employee e
JOIN t_department d
ON( e.department_id = d.id)
where d.name       <> 'MANAGER'
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(BIRTH_DATE, 'mon');

MONTH        LISTS                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
------------ ------------------------------------------
apr          NAME-3(Y)
jul          NAME-4(Y),NAME-5(Y),NAME-6(Not Defined)
oct          NAME-2(Y)
```

or simply:

```
select to_char(birth_date, 'mon') month, nvl(e.status,'Not Defined')status,
     listagg(e.name, ',') 
     WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY TO_CHAR(BIRTH_DATE, 'mon')) AS lists
FROM t_employee e
JOIN t_department d
ON( e.department_id = d.id)
where d.name       <> 'MANAGER'
group by to_char(birth_date, 'mon'),e.status;

MONTH        STATUS                           LISTS                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
------------ -------------------------------- -------
apr          Y                                NAME-3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
jul          Not Defined                      NAME-6                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
jul          Y                                NAME-4,NAME-5                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
oct          Y                                NAME-2
```